# Lock (encrypt) java Netbeans files for customer

Tags: java, netbeans

I make a program in Netbeans but I want my program files locked because I not want that any one can read or copy the source. How can I lock the files?

thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very broad question, but i'll try to help a little bit.

The best thing you could probably do for something written in java is called 'obfuscation', which means that your code is still readable, just very jumbled and very difficult to understand to a human

"Locking" files on a JVM language is an uphill battle that you probably won't ever win, if someone really really wants to see your source code and edit it, they can, it will just take some time, this actually applies to any language really, to be honest. No matter what you do, if someone is smart enough and really wants to edit your program, they can and will find a way, the best you can do is try to make it as hard as possible for them.

That being said, a decent obfuscator is enough to make most people look at your project and decide it probably isn't worth their time to manually deobfuscate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!